# Ansible: Skipping items in a loop based on item key's value

Tags: ansible

I'm fiddling around with loops and conditional skips.
Given the following playbook, everything works fine (mind the commented part, that I will use later on)

playbook.yml:

```
- name: Play Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    test1_var: "test1_var"
    test3_var: "{{ default(omit) }}" # omitted
    test4_var: # None
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: Test some skips in loops
        ansible.builtin.debug:
          msg: "Text:{{ item.text }}|Variable:{{item.variablez}}"
        loop:
          - text: "Should be logged"
            variablez: "{{ test1_var }}"
          - text: "Should be skipped"
          #- text: "Should be skipped"
          #  variablez: "{{ test3_var | default(omit) }}"
          - text: "Should be skipped"
            variablez: "{{ test4_var }}"
        when: item.variablez is defined and item.variablez != None
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Output:

```
TASK [Test some skips in loops] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [mosquitto -> localhost] => (item={'text': 'Should be logged', 'variablez': 'test1_var'}) => 
  msg: Text:Should be logged|Variable:test1_var
skipping: [mosquitto] => (item={'text': 'Should be skipped'}) 
skipping: [mosquitto] => (item={'text': 'Should be skipped', 'variablez': None})
```

The second item has no key `item.variablez` so it is skipped.
The third item is skipped because `item.variablez` is None.

Now when I uncomment the part

```
- text: "Should be skipped"
  variablez: "{{ test3_var | default(omit) }}" # Also "{{ default(omit) }}" leads to the same result
```

I would expect the item simply to be skipped. Because `item.variablez` and or `test3_var` is omitted. But instead the whole task is skipped:

```
PLAY [Play Test] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Test some skips in loops] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [mosquitto]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
mosquitto                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Now I try to understand why this is happening. Does anybody know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be due to a loop processing bug in ansible-core<2.14 (the changes in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/56116 make the loop execution more correct in 2.14), but the root cause is an invalid variable definition.

```yaml
    test3_var: "{{ default(omit) }}" # omitted
```

This is not a valid expression; `default()` is a filter, so it needs to receive a value. You probably meant this:

```yaml
    test3_var: "{{ omit }}" # omitted
```

Note that while this will fix the problem with the loop definition not being valid, you will still have a logic problem because `omit` and `None` are not the same thing.

`omit` is a variable holding a special string that can be used as a parameter and is treated by the execution engine as that parameter not being present, but outside of parameter processing it's just a normal string. Since `omit != None`, your task will run and output the value of `omit` as part of the message:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'text': 'Should be skipped', 'variablez': '__omit_place_holder__180f8c0850ccb5c85940241213b4e1590ec6c326'}) => {
    "msg": "Text:Should be skipped|Variable:__omit_place_holder__180f8c0850ccb5c85940241213b4e1590ec6c326"
```

If you want to use `omit` as a flag you need to check for it explicitly:

```yaml
- name: Play Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    test1_var: "test1_var"
    test3_var: "{{ omit }}" # omitted
    test4_var: # None
  tasks:
    - name: Test some skips in loops
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Text:{{ item.text }}|Variable:{{item.variablez}}"
      loop:
        - text: "Should be logged"
          variablez: "{{ test1_var }}"
        - text: "Should be skipped"
        - text: "Should be skipped"
          variablez: "{{ test3_var | default(omit) }}"
        - text: "Should be skipped"
          variablez: "{{ test4_var }}"
      when:
        - item.variablez is defined
        - item.variablez not in (None, omit)
```